# Django-countries and TastyPie: Get country name

Tags: python, django, rest, tastypie, django-countries

I got a model like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django_countries.fields import CountryField

class Location(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    country = CountryField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.company
```

Now I am using TastyPie for an API. I got a very simple model like this (even though I have had edited it with filters and fields before but had no success):

```
class LocationResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Location.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'location'
```

What it returns:

```
{"company": "testcompany", "country":"DE" "resource_uri": "/api/location/1/"}
```

What I would need though is  the country name, or even better, anything from the Country Field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can  add a dehydrate method for `country` to your `LocationResource`

```
def dehydrate_country(self, bundle):
    return bundle.obj.country.name
```

**`OR`**

if you are using **DRF** instantiate `Country field` like

```
 from django_countries.serializer_fields import CountryField

 country = CountryField(country_dict=True)
```

in your `serializer`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) While the `CountryField` didn't work for me (`unexpected keyword argument 'country_dict'), maybe because I misunderstood something. But using a `dehydrate` function was exactly what I needed!

Comment: you are right, actually it is for DRF serializer, See the update.

Comment: I am getting error: `django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: can't adapt type 'collections.OrderedDict'` when I use `country_dict = True`. So what could the possible cause?

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain the name from django_countries data dictionary

```
from django_countries.data import COUNTRIES

country_name = COUNTRIES[country_code]
```

Answer (score -1):

In case of DRF, little bit of tweaks to the serializer could work

```py
from django_countries.serializer_fields import CountryField
from django_countries.fields import CountryField as ModelCountryField


class CustomCountryMixin(CountryFieldMixin):
    """Custom mixin to serialize country with name instead of country code"""

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        for field in instance._meta.fields:
            if field.__class__ == ModelCountryField:
                if getattr(instance, field.name).name:
                    data[field.name] = getattr(instance, field.name).name
        return data



class StudentSerializer(CustomCountryMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ('mobile_number', 'study_destination', 'country_of_residence',
                  'university', 'study_level', 'course_start_date')
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Error - "'list' object has no attribute 'name'"